# Content type is not creating Parent properly

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, content-type, site-column

I am trying to create generic content type creation using following code.

```
// Create a Content Type Information object
                ContentTypeCreationInformation _customcontenttype = new ContentTypeCreationInformation();
                _customcontenttype.Name = SourceCT.Name;
                _customcontenttype.ParentContentType = TargetContentTypes.GetById(SourceCT.Parent.Id.ToString());//.Parent;
                _customcontenttype.Group = SourceCT.Group;

                // Create the content type
                ContentType myContentType = TargetContentTypes.Add(_customcontenttype);
                Global.targetClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

This code is generating content type properly, but it's not setting parent properly.
It always set 'item' as in parent of content type.

Please help.

Comment: What is SourceCT and what is it's Parent that you use as parent?

Answer (score 0):

This i have achieved by creating recursive function. Which checks and create parent content type if it's not exist.

Comment: Please can you add some sample code to your post. Without this it isn't really very helpful. Thanks [moderator]